# Bootstrap button group: What does "mr" do?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was just checking out the button group of [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/) 
and there is this:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
```

I could not find any explanation what "mr-2" actually does. The same with "mb-3" for the toolbar.

Can anyone explain it please to me? And how can I find out what attributes like this do if I don't have any internet? I mean there must be a class or something that shows the behavior right?

Comment: "If I don't have any internet"? You should be sure to grab an offline copy of the documentation from the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mb = margin-bottom, mr = margin-right

It's "Bootstrap short-hand" by making classes out of CSS styling.

You can look through the bootstrap.css file to find their CSS properties.

Comment: A more in-depth description: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/